# Trigger Rep recalc gives huge jump - incorrectly?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation

My rep on the P.Se site was 641 this morning.

The `/reputation` page showed a total of 645 or so, and I pressed the button to `Trigger Recalc`

It now [jumps to 905](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1681/jose) and the `/reputation` page shows a total of 905 as well. I'm not sure where the 260 came from - this discrepancy is only on p.se and not on SO, meta.so etc

Has anyone else faced this today?

I've checked that none of the CW answers have suddenly turned to scoring ones, they're still CW.

*I'm not complaining* - just wondering if I got someone else's stats by mistake?

Edit after Jeff's comment:

I've checked and think it's related [to this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48117/how-do-software-projects-go-over-budget-and-under-deliver/48123#48123) from May 2010 which was migrated over from SO on Feb 15 2011 **as CW**. But now I can see it has accumulated 290 rep on p.se on dates prior to the migration. This is original rep from SO which I think was not credited earlier on P.SE - but which I remember I did lose on SO when the migration happened.

So probably the rep did not get calculated all this while - but I'm sure I saw the breakdown only showing 645 this morning.

Comment: did new questions or answers you own get migrated here? that'd be my very first guess.

Comment: @Jeff: Nope, if so I should have lost 260 rep on SO as well ? I've checked the answers on p.se and they're all the same as before, dont seem any migrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reputation recalc does a few "fixups" as well, including some migration cleanup to ensure you get reputation for your content even with old migrations (we have increased the robustness of the migration process over time, but don't want to forget any old data).

You're seeing the result of this in action, enjoy your long lost rep!

Comment: he he did you develop this bit recently?  Thanks - this is the right answer for me.

Comment: @Jose - it's been in there a few months...but unless something major happens or you trigger it...a recalc won't be performed for quite some time.  In fact we have no schedule for global recalcs, only doing them out of necessity...it's quite an expensive operation at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You rep on Meta lags behind that on the main site - it's copied every hour or so.

The main ways you could have gained this rep is through posts you were down-voted on (or down-voted) have been deleted. This will return the reputation you lost - though this seems a lot of down-votes.

I wouldn't worry about it.